# Why do you need quotes here in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix

```
    if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]; then
    ...
    fi
```

Why can't I have something like:

```
if [ $a -gt $b ]; then
        ...
        fi
```

for Bash?

Comment: Because word-splitting and expansion.

Comment: @CodeGnome: But does it matter for integer comparison? Don't think so! The 2nd example will work just fine.

Comment: Because if either `a` or `b` are empty, the expression will be invalid. If you do not want to quote, use `[[ ... ]]`

Comment: Technically @Cyrus is correct, but it is good practice to always quote within `test` or `[ ... ]` (synonymous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With arithmetic operator `-gt` (greater-than) `$a` and `$b` must contain integers and no quotes are necessary.

Comment: Man it must be a tough crowd tonight to get dinged on a correct answer...

Comment: Sorry, no. The use of the operator doesn't cast the variables. If *$a* or *$b* are not integers, or unset, you will get `-bash: [: : integer expression expected`.

Comment: Granted, but I don't think that is what was represented. The answer simply says **"[To be valid]...** `$a` and `$b` must contain integers and **[in that case]** no quotes are necessary." as I read it. (now I do agree they should be quoted for the reasons you give)

Comment: If `$a` or/and `$b` are empty/contain no integer (with or without quoting) there is always the described error message. When you use `[ ... ]`, you must ensure that the variables contain an integer.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think this answer is borderline. The question was `Why do you need quotes here in Bash?` -- well, you need it because the variables could be unset, among other things.

Comment: Here's an example where the comparison is true but the operands are not integers: `a=1 b='1 -o foo'`

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes here for correction -- for example, to avoid code injection. Let's say you have that script unquoted and you let me input numbers to tell me which one is greater.

I input:

```
a="1"
b="1 -o -e /home/foo"
```

Since you didn't quote, you're now going to evaluate

```
[ 1 -gt 1 -o -e /home/foo ]
```

and tell me that `b` is greater if `/home/foo` exists.

Your number comparison script has suddenly become a simplistic file browser that I can use to examine your system to find active users, running processes, installed software, hardware configuration and such.

This may not matter in practice, but when it's so easy to do right, you might as well quote.

Comment: Great insight. I think one should always quote variable expansions -- it's "cheap" and there are so many cases when not doing so will mean trouble.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You have provided no sample input, but it's likely that your variables are unset, empty, or don't contain integers. To make your scripts more robust, you should always quote your variables, test for conditions like empty or unset variables, or perform other validations if you can't guarantee the contents of your variables or are consuming user input.

### Invalid Expansions

Unless you've explicitly declared your variables as integers, and sometimes even when you do, there are several cases where your comparison will be invalid. For example:

```
$ unset a b; a=1; [ $a -gt $b ]
-bash: [: 1: unary operator expected
```

You have a number of options, but the easiest is to use the Bash expression operators instead of the single brackets which are actually equivalent to */bin/test*. This handles empty expansions and other use cases more gracefully. For example:

```
# Here, *b* is unset so *a* is "greater."
$ unset a b; a=1; [[ $a -gt $b ]]; echo $?
0

# This time *a* is unset, so the expression is false.
$ unset a b; b=1; [[ $a -gt $b ]]; echo $?
1
```

## Declaring Variables as Integers *May* Help

You still have to beware of unexpected casts, though. For example:

```
$ unset a b; a='foo'; b='1'; [[ $a -gt $b ]]; echo $?
1

$ echo $a
foo
```

Better is the use of `declare -i` to force integer casting, but that will still cause unexpected results if you don't validate your inputs. For example:

```
$ unset a b; declare -i a='foo' b='1'; [[ $a -gt $b ]]; echo $?
1

$ echo $a
0
```

By declaring your variables, you force the values to be integers, but strings will be assigned as zero. This is likely not what you're expecting.

### Validations and Defensive Quoting

While overkill for simple scripts, this is what a more robust script would look like.

```
unset a b
a='foo'
b='1'

for var in "$a" "$b"; do
    if [[ -z "$var" ]] || [[ ! "$var" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
        echo "Variable invalid: ${var}" > /dev/stderr
    fi    
done

[[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]]
echo "$?"
```

Note that in this case, the quotes and braces are not strictly necessary, but are there to show good defensive programming. You can rarely go wrong in Bash by using them liberally, and they will often save you a great deal of head-scratching and debugging.